# python: edit ISO file directly

Tags: python, file, file-format, iso

1. Is it possible to take an ISO file and edit a file in it directly, i.e. not by unpacking it, changing the file, and repacking it?
2. It is possible to do 1. from Python? How would I do it?

Comment: damn how is this already the top google hit for "python edit iso" (52 mins later)?

Comment: Google just _really_ likes SO!  On another note, I don't think it's possible to modify an ISO image in-place due to the way the ISO filesystem is structured. I could be entirely wrong, though. Either way, have you looked into libcdio's python bindings? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycdio/ I don't think libcdio can do what you want, but it's the easiest cross-platform solution I know of to do low-level operations on ISO images in python... Good luck, either way!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Of course, as with any file.
2. It can be done with open/read/write/seek/tell/close operations on a file. Pack/unpack the data with struct/ctypes. It would require serious knowledge of the contents of ISO, but I presume you already know what to do. If you're lucky you can try using mmap - the interface to file contents string-like.

Comment: i mean, without implementing the entire ISO spec from scratch, which is what i'd have to do if i were to use those operations on it...

Comment: That's true and I was afraid you'd say something like this. If you are to fiddle with a few bytes inside an ISO, it may still be worth it. If you are to, i.e. replace a file's content with another, possibly differing in size, you'd be in need of reconstructing the filesystem, just like the CD writers do.

Comment: this seems to be the answer, at least taking the comment into account

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [Hachoir](https://pypi.org/project/hachoir/), a Python library to "view and edit a binary stream field by field"?  I haven't had a need to try it myself, but ISO 9660 is listed as a [supported parser format](https://hachoir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parser.html#file-system).

Answer (score 3):

You can use for listing and extracting, I tested the first.

https://github.com/barneygale/iso9660/blob/master/iso9660.py

```
import iso9660
cd = iso9660.ISO9660("/Users/murat/Downloads/VisualStudio6Enterprise.ISO")
for path in cd.tree():
    print path
```

https://github.com/barneygale/isoparser

```
import isoparser
iso = isoparser.parse("http://www.microsoft.com/linux.iso")

print iso.record("boot", "grub").children
print iso.record("boot", "grub", "grub.cfg").content
```

Answer (score 3):

[PyCdlib](https://github.com/clalancette/pycdlib) can read and edit ISO-9660 files, as well as Joliet, Rock Ridge, UDF, and El Torito extensions. It has a bunch of detailed examples in its [documentation](https://clalancette.github.io/pycdlib/examples.html), including one showing how to [edit a file in-place](https://clalancette.github.io/pycdlib/example-modifying-file-in-place.html). At the time of writing, it cannot add or remove files, or edit directories. However, it is still actively maintained, in contrast to the libraries linked in older answers.